# cardano-wallet-js

Tags: wallet

I'd like to play around with cardano-wallet-js and see what can be automated with transactions and better understand how things work.

I get that I need first to install cardano-wallet and [this](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-wallet#getting-started) is the only instruction I found on how to install it. But I incur in problems as I don't know how to use Docker `ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker at http+docker://localhost - is it running?` even though docker service is running.

Is there any more throughout instruction on how to install cardano-wallet and then cardano-wallet-js?

Is there any other way to use cardano-wallet-js?

are there other tools that make it easier for a non very technical guy as me to make scripts for transactions and wallets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have experience with docker, don't use it. It just adds another layer of complications. The easiest way to get a wallet up and running is to get the release binaries from the assets at the bottom of this page for your architecture: https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-wallet/releases/tag/v2021-12-15

Then you'll need to start both the node and wallet processes on your system. At that point you can run your nodejs code that talks to the API.

On the node side, read this to get a working node:
https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/running-cardano/

On the wallet side, it's the serve command here that you want to run: https://input-output-hk.github.io/cardano-wallet/user-guide/cli:

At that point you can use cardano-wallet CLI to test it out and eventually point your nodejs code at wallet API to run your custom application.